# How can I push to a mysql database from Mamp to my domain?

Tags: php, mysql

I just made a blog post on my localhost machine (I.E. Draft) now I want to update the remote MYSQL database that is now running on the machine.

So in analgous terms when uploading the files, I just run PHPStorm and include upload to remote database, is there a way to do that or a PHP file that will administrate the process

My pseudocode guess will be:

localhost:admin.php

if publish clicked, connect to remote sql and copy entry.

Comment: You want to upload mysql database files to server?

Comment: the normal way (esp. if it's a new database) is to generate a SQL script (like a backup) from the local DB, then execute it on the remote DB to create the tables etc.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly you need to remotely access your database right?
If so you have some options, starting with:

**1) Use a tunnel over ssh with mysql [workbench!](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)**

How? Example Here: [Standard TCP/IP over SSH Connection Method](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-methods-ssh.html)

You can import your local database by reverse engineering and after that simply accessing to database menu, you can synchronise model with remote database etc. That is to grant that both databases have the same structure. You can put your sql and execute as well... there are plenty of options here.

2) You can also access your remote database with a data source under **PHPSTORM**. here it is how you can do it! [Managing Data Sources](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/managing-data-sources.html)

3) Via terminal, if you have access to root simple scp your sql file to remote and after that well update remote database.

**Backup database:** `mysqldump -u username -p database_to_backup > backup_name.sql`

**Restore database** `mysql -u username -p database_name < backup_name.sql`

4) Make you sql server accessible to the world (not recommended)!
Steps include creating a new user or upgrade an existent user privileges options are wide here.

Read [this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/mysql_remote.html) article: it says pretty much everything!

5) Install [phpmyadmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) (not recommended)

Comment: Advice so good I'll upvote despite the plug for paid software ;)